# For Each Statement to loop across bunch of textbox values

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a bunch of textboxes which will be populated with values selected from a dropdown.

Lets say out of 10 textboxes, values were populated in 5: `Rinv1` to `Rinv5`.

How can I loop through these and collect those values?

I am trying to use a `for each` loop and collect those values in an array and then store those values in a field in my DB.

```
Rolls = Array(Me.Rinv1, Me.Rinv2, Me.Rinv3)
Dim RollName As Variant

'iterating using For each loop.
For Each Item In Rolls
    RollName = RollName & Item
Next

Forms![LabelSHEETER2].JOB = RollName
```

Some syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest iterating over the control names rather than the control objects, for example, something along the lines of the following:

```
Dim Itm
Dim RollName As String
For Each Itm in Split("Rinv1 Rinv2 Rinv3")
    RollName = RollName & Me.Controls(Itm).Value
Next Itm
Forms![LabelSHEETER2].JOB = RollName
```

Comment: better answer here!

Comment: Rinv1, Rinv2, Rinv3 and so on are textbox names...not the actual value. The value might change. When you say control names over control object, what does that mean? I apologize if that's a very naive question.

Comment: ok, i read some definations online and tried to follow your code. It works like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @NewAtSQL You're most welcome. For completeness: each Control object (textbox, listbox, combobox etc.) in the Controls collection of a Form has a `Name` property which may be used to acquire the object from the Controls collection. My suggestion was to iterate over the names of such objects, rather than the objects themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to get the values of all TextBoxes and combining them into a string

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control
Dim str As String

For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
        str = str & ctrl.Text
    End If
Next ctrl

MsgBox str

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through the Form controls and check for name matches. 
This way, you don't need to leave the Form design window again to change your code or add objects to an array.

```
Dim ctl As Control
Dim strRollName As String

For Each ctl in Me.Controls
    If ctl.Name Like "Rinv*" Then
        strRollName = strRollName & ctl.Value & " "
    End If
Next ctl
```